# Accessing local ip address using xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-transport-security

Im trying to acces a local ip address so that i can change/update information on a local raspberry pi. Namely im using the following:

```
https://github.com/Jopyth/MMM-Remote-Control
```

ive updated my plist  to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>en</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>http://192.168.0.40</key>  // need to add your domain name of webservice
                <dict>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                    <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                    <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                    <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                    <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
                    <false/>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>LaunchScreen</string>
        <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
        <string>Main</string>
        <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
        <array>
            <string>armv7</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

but i still get a blank, albeit dark page when loading on a sim or device.

Im making the most basic of apps so that my brother can access his magic mirror when he is home to update it but i cant seem to see the local ip adress. Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you going to submit this to Apple, or just give it to your brother and update the provisioning profile for the app each year?

Comment: Exception domains don't work for IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the real problem is that ATS exception **domains** do not work with IP addresses. It only works with **domain names**.

Options:

**Option 1 - disable ATS**

Turning off ATS altogether is a not a great idea if you are submitting your app to the app store - doing so will cause you to justify that decision if you wish to submit to the app store when Apple starts enforcing that rule. Normally I do not recommend this as an option on SO. However, considering that you are puttinga hard coded IP address in there, I suspect this is a single use app created for a particular use case, and you will not need to submit to Apple for review (you will probably be installing directly on a device using a development provisioning profile). If that's the case, I would just disable ATS entirely using the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key in your Info.plist.

[image]

This will disable all ATS protections, but if your app is only communicating with the local network entity via HTTPS, App Transport Security wouldn't have been protecting anything anyway.

**Option 2 - use NSAllowsLocalNetworking**

If you put both `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` and `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` in your Info.plist, in iOS 9, you will disable ATS entirely, but in iOS 10 (the first version that supported the `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` setting), iOS will ignore the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` and only disable ATS on local network calls.  This would be more secure, but if you're ONLY making local networking calls, I would just disable ATS (Option 1).

**Option 3 - xip.io**

If you want to leave ATS on, others have had success using xip.io service to "convert" the local IP address to a domain name. So you would add xip.io to the Exception domains, set the subvalue for NSIncludesSubdomains to true. Then when you connect to your domain, instead of connecting to 192.168.0.40 you would connect to 192.168.0.40.xip.io